# Enumerating Numeric keys for Flowtype'd Objects

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am adding flowtype to a side project of mine, and am coming across a confusing error for the following code.

This works as expected (by throwing an error):

```
/* @flow */
function test(
  events: {
    [event: number]: {
    }
  }
): void {
    events['hi'];
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
8:     events['hi'];
       ^ property `hi` is a string. This type is incompatible with
4:     [event: number]: {
               ^ number
```

However, this does NOT work:

```
/* @flow */
function test(
  events: {
    [event: number]: {
    }
  }
): void {
  for (const event: number in events) {
  }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
for (const event: number in events) {
                  ^ string. This type is incompatible with
for (const event: number in events) {
                  ^ number
```

I'm wondering why this is? [According to the official documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#objects-as-maps), Flow is smart enough to infer precise values for the type of an Object when using it as a map.

Is it because the typing for for loops thinks that the object would potentially contain other string-keyed items? How can I iterate over this while keeping the explicit type safety?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Flow, really. Objects in Javascript can only have string and symbol properties. Everything else is implicitly converted to strings when you use square brackets to access properties. When you use `for in` or `Object.keys` though you will always get strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated the question so it's more clear why I'm asking this. I realize that all objects are keyed with strings, but Flow is supposed to be smart enough to understand explicit types when using Objects as maps (as people are often wont to do so). I assume this follows with enumeration, considering that iteration over maps is a common practice as well. See [this section in the documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#objects-as-maps).

Answer (score -1):

I came across [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1736) when searching for an answer, which may indicate there is currently just a bug with the for-in loop handling of types.